# Cannot edit cells of my DataGrid WPF Framework 4.5

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

My ObservableCollection has three items, and the rows are consistently shown in the datagrid.
I cannot turn into edit mode a single cell of my DataGrid. I tried click, click-click, double-click, F2,…,  but the whole row stay selected. How can I let the user edit the datagrid. 
I found similar datagrid edit-questions in other posts but no-one solved my problem. Here is the code (WPF NetFramework 4.5). Pursposely, only the first column is non-editable (readonly).

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200"  >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Formulation" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormulationStr}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormulationStr}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="volume Diff" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding volumeDiff}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding volumeDiff}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have placed `TextBlock` in `cell template` as well as in `cell editing template`. That's why you are not noticing any change on pressing F2 and double-clicking the cell since no matter what it will always be `TextBlock` which you can't edit.

Either placed `TextBox` in your `CellEditingTemplate` like this -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Formulation" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormulationStr}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FormulationStr}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or either simply use the `DataGridTextColumn` in place of `DataGridTemplateColumn` which internally provides the support what are you trying to achive by the above code -

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Formulation" Width="100" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding FormulationStr}" />
```

Comment: I can paste text into the cell but I can't type anything into it - any ideas